# iphone 3d library with physics

Tags: physics, 3d, iphone

are there any light 3d iphone libraries that must have:

- Physics ( ragdoll physics )
- 3D scene graph
- Advanced lighting (lightmapping and stuff)
- Sound engine
- Ability to import 3D model from blender, 3d studio max, etc.

it should preferably be mature and have no bugs.
i have seen cocos3d but many say it is riddled with bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of game engines/frameworks for iPhone 3D development (but I am not sure whether they satisfy all your requirements):

- http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/
- http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/
- http://sio2interactive.com/
- http://www.ogre3d.org/
- http://code.google.com/p/isgl3d/
- http://code.google.com/p/galaxyengine/
- http://www.udk.com/mobile

Answer (score 1):

Possible candidates are [UDK](http://udk.com/), [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) or [ShiVa](http://www.stonetrip.com/).
These are game-engines and not "libraries" in the common sense. There's no library that covers all your requirements, as each of your bullet point would be a library on its own.